# Are there programs that allow a user to follow and report on what a windows 7 service does over time?

Tags: windows-7, networking, services

I am having a problem with the NSI service on my Windows 7 laptop. It progressively takes up more memory and eventually starts to suck up half the CPU constantly. I am looking for a program that can allow a semi-technical person like myself to monitor, track, and see what it is that NSI is doing. The idea is to try and track down the cause of this issue. I do not want to constantly restart the system trying to play whack a bug. System stability is a concern for me at this point.

I have tried numerous times to fix this issue, the only thing I have not done is to take it to someone like Geek Squad, however I have sensitive files like financial docs on my system and am hesitant to allow strangers access to my system outside of my purview.

Any advice on how to figure this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hotfix? [A memory leak in Network Store Interface Service (NSI) occurs unexpectedly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2950358)

Comment: Have tried both. My svchost is currently around 1,146,000k memory. That svchost holds NSI.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and see exactly what processes are doing. That NSI service is probably running inside svchost.exe, which means you'll have to filter out everything else.

Comment: Have process monitor, not very knowledgable about it though. Maybe I am not able to read it right but I am unable to locate what causes NSI to hog so much memory.

Comment: Open the Filter dialog. Select Command Line in the first drop down menu, and "is" in the second one. In the the third drop down menu choose **C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalService** and click Add. This should set you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for the advice spherical_dog, I had to restart the system since NSI's memory was over 1 million by that point. If (I hope) NSI starts acting up again I will boot up the process monitor and go looking for the cause. Any advice on what I should looking for?

Comment: What should I look for or do? I have activated the program, and have found something which might be paydirt, however I am unsure if what I found is actually the problem or not. How do I tell if I found something indicating a problem? Is there someone I can send the log to who could help?

Comment: Download [VMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx), select svchost.exe after it has used an excessive amount of memory and post a screenshot.

Comment: SVCHost at 98,820k memory. Here is the link to the screenshot as per your request. http://postimg.org/image/7ygliph0n/

Comment: Darn the editing rules here. Data file is at link. The file is VMMap data .mmp https://temp-share.com/f/lcxfrkhjjl/45ee2b8d12f835571b5a4803c55a6f8f80f269536581481f75d9e9cb22628a3e

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? svchost obviously shouldn't be allocating that much memory. One thing that might be worth trying is capturing a dump with something like procdump and opening it in Windbg.

Comment: I have not beyond my workaround of simply cutting the connection to the network when the laptop is not in use. That seems to either keep the memory from building up or, after 12 hours or more, drop the memory down to about 45,000 memory. I did notice that that SVCHost was creating quite a lot of errors on VMMap, but beyond that, I am a little out of my depth honestly. I have never done a dump before, let alone how to read one. Any further advice? Should I post the dump here? Is there a 'preferred' method for submitting a dump, needed files, etc?

Comment: You can do it more easily with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx). Run it as administrator, navigate to the instance of svchost that is using the most memory, right click and Create Full Dump. Then download [Windbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx), point it to Microsoft's symbol server, and open the dump that you captured. Write `!analyze -v` in the command line and see if anything valuable shows up. I'm not sure what else can be done if this doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I got the full dump from Process Explorer like you said. Honestly the Windbg stuff looks little past my realm of knowledge and certain parts of the legalese section make me nervous. Is there someone I could/should ask to look at this? It's not as if the full dump file will contain anything potentially damaging right? Thank you so much for your advice, you have been a real help.